# Rainfall distribution

Tags: distributions, continuous-data, discrete-data

1. After calculating the SPI (standard precipitation index) we can derive rainfall variables such as duration, severity, intensity ... My question is severity is under continuous variable. How about duration? Is it discrete? or continuous?
2. We can joint two difference distribution for example gamma and Weibull (both under continuous) using copula for example. My question is can we joint two different class (continuous and discrete distribution together)

Comment: "How about duration? is it discrete? or continuous?" You have not given us enough information to answer this.

Comment: i have 2 rainfall variables, namely duration and severity. severity is continuous data. how about duration? is it continuous data too? because i see one journal he use continuous distribution to fit the duration variable..

Comment: You simply repeated your question without giving more information about the variable. Duration could be discrete, or it might be effectively continuous, depending on how it's recorded and treated (if you record it to the minute, second, or hundredth of a second, it's effectively continuous, if you record it to the day, it would be pretty odd to call it continuous). Since it might be be in days in one paper and in hours in a second and in minutes or even seconds in a third, *YOU* must tell us what's going on -- we can't guess for you.

Comment: Im so sorry. My fault...okay variable duration is derive from SPI. Example D=3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,5,1,3,3,...,4 recorded in months.. im still confuse why some author treat duration variable as continuous. for me its totally discrete

Comment: Can you please add new information as an edit to the Question?

Answer (score 3):

The *actual duration* will be continuous, but the way you record it may make it effectively discrete. If you're recording by rounding to some sufficiently large unit so that it only takes a few different values, it's usually not reasonable to treat the recorded value as continuous (though if you want to perform inference about the underlying continuous variable, you may need to deal with it as an interval-censored continuous variable instead of a discrete one -- that depends on what you want to achieve). If you're recording it to come very fine precision (where many dozens or hundreds of different values are likely to be observed), then it's often best to keep treating it as continuous.

[However, where you draw the line depends on your needs and what is available / convenient / accepted.]

To respond to the last question, yes, a bivariate distribution can be over a pair of variables where one is continuous and the other is discrete.

For example, you could have a bivariate distribution whose margins are negative-binomial and gamma, say.

This presents no particular difficulty (over the usual issues of using copulas with discrete distributions more generally).